# Necesito agregar un texto php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, ckeditor

Necesito agregar un texto que defino en un textarea que esta al final del codigo pero al querer ingresarlo por primera vez me sale variable indefinida como hago para corregir esto adjunto el codigo

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1 or
$_SESSION['user_permision'] != "Administrador") 
{
    header("location: login.php"); 
    exit;                                              
    }


require_once ("config/db.php");
require_once ("config/conexion.php");

$active_ticket="active";    
$title="Prestamos   | Simple Stock";
        $Nticket= $_GET['Nticket'];
     $incidencia= $_GET['incidencia'];
        $tema= $_GET['tema'];
        $detalle= $_GET['detalle'];
         $firstname= $_GET['firstname'];
        $text = $_POST['editor'];
      ?>
     <html>
      <head>
<?php include("head.php");
    include("navbarhelp.php");?>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="subject">Asunto:<strong><?php echo $tema; ?></strong></div>
    <div id="ticketThread">
    <table class="thread-entry message" cellspacing="0" 
      cellpadding="1"width="800" boder="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>
            <div>
                <span class="textra"></span>
                <span><?php echo $firstname; ?></span>
                </div>    
            </th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="thread-body"><div><?php echo $detalle ?></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="thread-entry response" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" 
      width="800" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                Respuesta <span class="textra"></span>
                <span></span>
                </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr><br>
                <td class="thread-body"><br><div><?php echo $text ?><br>
    </div></td></tr>
            </tbody></table></div>

    <form action="respuestas.php?Nticket=<?php echo $Nticket?>&incidencia=<?
   =$incidencia?>&tema=<?=$tema?>&detalle=<?=$detalle?>&firstname=<?
   =$firstname?>" 
  method="POST">
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>

        <input type="submit"  value="Respuesta">
   </form>
        </body>

             <?php 

if(isset($_POST['editor'])){

    $text = $_POST['editor'];
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ticket SET Respuesta='".$text."'  
       WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'");



}

   ?>
```

esto es antes de ingresar un valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues de ingresar un valor en el textarea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno el código `$text = $_POST['editor'];` que tienes en la línea 22 lo puedes quitar por que realmente ahí no lo necesitas ya que más abajo en tu código estás preguntando por esa misma variable para proceder a guardarla:

```
if(isset($_POST['editor'])){
   $text = $_POST['editor'];
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ticket SET Respuesta='".$text."'  
       WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'");
}
```

Ahora imagino que lo que querías lograr era obtener la respuesta que ya se había guardado con anterioridad en el sistema para lo cual deberías de hacer una consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT Respuesta FROM ticket WHERE Nticket = $Nticket";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Con esto capturas el valor que hayas ingresado para posteriormente actualizarlo de ser necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en la línea 22; estás buscando una variable `POST` de igual forma que variables `GET`. Intenta cambiar:

```
$text = $_POST['editor'];
```

Por algo así:

```
!isset($_POST['editor']) ? : $text = $_POST['editor'];
```

Normalmente uno revisa dentro de la variable `$_SERVER` para saber que tipo de request se hizo, `POST` o `GET` y se toman decisiones en el flujo de tus scripts a partir de ahí pero esa ejemplo que te comparto también funciona.

Revisando un poco más a fondo, parece que también puedes simplemente eliminar la línea 22 ya que estás haciendo lo mismo al final del script:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['editor'])){

  $text = $_POST['editor'];
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está cuando cargas todo, el PHP, captura de una vez los valores que le indicas en líneas 15 a la 22, los anteriores a `$text`, no dan error porque están por el método $_GET, pero `$text` está por $_POST y al momento de cargar no le has pasado nada por $_POST.

opciones de solución:

1. Ordena el código.
2. Usa AJAX.
3. Cambia `$text` al método `$_GET`.